# Using multiple models for django ecommerce cart

Tags: django, django-models, cart

I'm making a cart for an ecommerce project that I am working on, at the moment the cart does work. However it only works for one model and I'm not sure how to make it work with more than one.

This is my contexts.py file in my cart folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from courses.models import Course
from food_order.models import Food_order


def cart_contents(request):
    """
    Ensures that the cart contents are available when rendering
    every page
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

    cart_items = []
    total = 0
    course_count = 0

    for id, quantity in cart.items():
        course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=id)
        total += quantity * course.price
        course_count += quantity
        cart_items.append({'id': id, 'quantity': quantity, 'course': course})

    return {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total': total, 'course_count': course_count}
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse

# Create your views here.
def view_cart(request):
    """A View that renders the cart contents page"""
    return render(request, "cart.html")


def add_to_cart(request, id):
    """Add a quantity of the specified product to the cart"""
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))

    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    if id in cart:
        cart[id] = int(cart[id]) + quantity      
    else:
        cart[id] = cart.get(id, quantity) 

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('index'))


def adjust_cart(request, id):
    """
    Adjust the quantity of the specified product to the specified
    amount
    """
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

    if quantity > 0:
        cart[id] = quantity
    else:
        cart.pop(id)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('view_cart'))
```

So I have 2 different classes I would like to be able to add to the cart from 2 different places on the ecommerce site. I am just uncertain how to acheive this.

If I do something along the lines of:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from courses.models import Course
from food_order.models import Food_order


def cart_contents(request):
    """
    Ensures that the cart contents are available when rendering
    every page
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

    cart_items = []
    total_food_order = 0
    total_course = 0
    total = 0
    product_count = 0

    for id, quantity in cart.items():
        course = get_object_or_404(Course, pk=id)
        food_order = get_object_or_404(Food_order, pk=id)
        total_course += quantity * course.price
        total_food_order += quantity * food_order.price
        product_count += quantity
        cart_items.append({'id': id, 'quantity': quantity, 'course': course, 'food_order':food_order})

    total = total_course + total_food_order
    return {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total': total, 'product_count': product_count}
```

Then the resulting `cart_items` will be:

```
[{'id': '1', 'quantity': 1, 'course': <Course: Basic Order Taking>, 'food_order': <Food_order: Onions>}, {'id': '2', 'quantity': 3, 'course': <Course: Advanced Order Taking>, 'food_order': <Food_order: Peppers>}]
```

I understand why it's doing this, but I cannot think of a way to adjust my code to get the desired result. Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an base model for all your models that need to be added to the cart, and use multi-table inheritence.

```
class BaseCartItem(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable_false)
    ....

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        self.item_type = self._get_item_type()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_item_type(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Course(BaseCartItem):
    ....

    def _get_item_type(self):
        return "Course"

class FoodOrder(BaseCartItem):
    ....

    def _get_item_type(self):
        return "Food Order"


#  if you want to add to the db
class Cart(models.Model)
    item = models.ForeignKey(BaseCartItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ....
```

And in the views everything remains the same. You just use the ids of the base model rather than the child models.

The `cart_contents` is simplified a bit

```
def cart_contents(request):
    """
    Ensures that the cart contents are available when rendering
    every page
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

    cart_items = []
    item_groups = defaultdict(int)
    total = 0
    product_count = 0

    items_map = {
        item.id: item
        for item in BaseCartItem.objects.filter(id__in=cart.keys()
    }

    for id, quantity in cart.items():
        item = items_map[id]
        item_group[item.item_type] += quantity * item.price
        product_count += quantity
        cart_items.append({'id': id, 'quantity': quantity, 'course': item, 'food_order':item})

    total = sum(item_groups.values())
    return {'cart_items': cart_items, 'total': total, 'product_count': product_count}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I follow what you are saying for the most part. For the `BaseCartItem`, where would that go? [My GitHub](https://github.com/kennedydmb/pizza-the-pie). Each of the models that I've made exists within the folder that it will be used it. i.e Food_order is in food_order/models.py. Would I make a new models.py at the top level?

Comment: ah... maybe if you have a common app you can put it in that...      usually you would put similar things together. I'm assuming each app has a lot of logic related to each model, so it might be good to have a common app with common logic